# Magento webpage won't display and want to delete all public_html and re-install

Tags: backup, fatal-error

I wanted to know whether is it fine if I delete the ENTIRE CONTENTS of `/home/user/public_html` directory of a user then re-install with a zip file?

I have a backup that I want to use because my magento website now is not working.

My problem was that I could not load my magento webpage (backend and frontend) due to an error within my public_html:

```
PHP Fatal error: class 'Mage_Admin_Helper_Data' not found in /home/company/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php on line 123
```

So recently I decided to install new update to a 1.9.1 version in magento however I disocvered later that the extensions I also want to download are not compatible with the newest version.

So I decided to delete the extension files I updated and upload the old extensions again within `app/var/package`

However this caused great error and now the frontend and admin of my website won't load.

So I just want to erase everything and install the backup and I was wondering how I can do this?

I don't want to loose any of my contents. I just want my website up and running again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a backup, yes you can remove all files and just replace them with your backup. You may also want to do the same thing for the database as well if you have the database backup.